# Return values in celery tasks for after_return method

Tags: python, django, task, return-value, celery

I've got a chain of celery tasks and implemented each task as a class inheriting the Celery Task model.

The Celery Task model has a `def run()` method that is required for the task to run.

There is also the ability to have an `def after_return` method, which will automatically trigger after the task (the run method) has been ran and returned a value.

One of the params in the `after_return` method is `retval`, which should be the return value of the `run` task. However, I cannot seem to get that to work.

Example class (basic):

```
from celery.task import Task
from utils import log as logging


class Test(Task):

    name = "test.create"
    soft_time_limit = 60
    ignore_result = False

    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):    
        return 'test string'

    def after_return(self, status, retval, task_id, args, kwargs, einfo):
        logging.info("Return value of test task: %s" % retval)
```

In this case, `retval` should equal `test string`. Instead, it is None.

Does anyone know if I am missing something simple?

Comment: I'm confused: has the "chain" anything to do with your problem? What happens if you don't chain your celery tasks but run this one in isolation?

Comment: If I run this in isolation, I still don't see "test string" as the return value in the after_return method.

Comment: Ok. Why do you need `abstract = True`?

Comment: Actually, edited. That was a mistake.

Comment: Would be great to have a look at the code where you launch the task. Right now, I don't see any reason why it doesn't work. Having your version of Celery would be nice too.